# Why not UIImage itself but UIImage view

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, uipickerview

I'm learning to develop apps for Iphone. I follow a book by Apress which I find very useful. But as nothing is perfect some issues are not well described and just skipped.In one of the applications I have to assign five images to each of the five components of a pickerview. But my question is why do/can not we use an instance of UImage itself but UIImageView to display on the picker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in above question you are asking why we can not use `UIImage` instead of `UIImageView` as component for `UIPickerView`.

`UIImage` is subclass of `NSObject` class, If we talk in terms of **M-V-C** its a ***M(model)***. and model in itself is nothing until its used.

`UIImageView` on the other hand is subclass of `UIView` which stands for ***V(view)*** in **M-V-C** so it uses your model for its contents.

So, they are two different things, not alternate. Also, if you go through `UIPickerView`'s class documentation then you will find that it has method

```
- (UIView *)viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

that configures view for specified row component. so it meanse we need view(`UIImageView`) and not the model class(`UIImage`). here for component you can return subclass of UIView.

Please refer apple's documentation.

Thanks,

Comment: Thank you, Ravin for your comprehensive explanation.It seems you've completely understood the principles of MVC as if you're yourself invented the whole thing. I hope I'll one they be as competent as you on this.

Answer (score 1):

You need a frame to place your photo, similarly You need UIImageView as place holder to place UIImage.

Answer (score 0):

UIImage is just an Image loaded from file. View is able to handle touch events and only Views are displayed.